# Checking if an element is part of a JSON array with no keys

Tags: postgresql

Assume a table `T` with an attribute `j` of type `jsonb`. How do I check if the string `'x'` is part of a array stored in `j` in the format `["a", "b", "c"]` (a valid JSON array with no keys)?

Answer (score 2):

you can either use `?` for a single element:

```
the_column  ? 'x'
```

Or if you want to check for multiple values you can use the `@>` operator

```
the_column @> '["x", "y"]'
```

Both conditions assume that the array is not stored as a nested element (e.g. `{list: ["a", "b", "c"]}'

More details in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)